# On-topic help center spring cleaning

Tags: discussion

All righty folks, the [on-topic page in the help center](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is pretty wordy, and we can probably make it more useful to users by:

- making it shorter
- moving the longer details into a canonical "summarize the site scope" meta post

We can also proofread while we're at it.

So let's do that collaboratively here. There's an answer with the current help center text below; we can edit from there.

Answer (score 1):

---

## Help center

---

**Board and Card Games Stack Exchange** is for expert Q&A from people who like playing, discussing the strategy of, and getting rules clarifications of board games, designing board games or modifying the rules of existing board games.

#### How do we define board games?

Please see [this meta question](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/174/if-you-cant-sit-down-at-a-table-and-play-it-its-not-a-board-or-card-game-goo/180#180) for the full discussion, the summary is:

1. Be playable on or around a table
2. Have objective rules of play and win conditions
3. Offer dynamic challenges, either through other players, randomization, or both
4. Be playable by hand, by human players implementing all of the rules

#### What are some examples of board games that are on topic here?

This is far from a complete list, but we have many questions on the following:

- Collectible Card Games

  - Magic:The Gathering
  - Pokemon
- "German" style board games

  - Dominion
  - Settlers of Catan
  - Carcassonne
- Traditional board games

  - Axis&Allies
  - Monopoly
- Traditional card games

  - Bridge
  - Poker
- Strategic games

  - Chess
  - Go
- Cooperative board games

  - Battlestar Galactica
  - Arkham Horror
- Minature wargames (including the preparation of miniatures/terrain/etc.)

  - Warhammer 40k
  - Warmachine
  - Battletech

For a question to be on topic, it must relate to a game that is on topic, but the particular instance that the question is referring to may loosen those rules. Questions about playing games with giant pieces will make a game not playable around a table, but if it's a game that *could be* or *is normally* played around a table, it's fine. Questions about Go problems or Chess problems are fine, even if they are static puzzles, since they are related to a dynamic game. Questions about computer implementations of board games are fine.

For more help, see ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](/help/dont-ask)

If your question is not specifically on-topic for Board and Card Games Stack Exchange, it may be on topic for [another Stack Exchange site](http://stackexchange.com/sites). **We're not the right place to ask questions about:**

- Computer games, try [gaming.stackexchange.com](http://gaming.stackexchange.com)
- Role Playing games, try [rpg.stackexchange.com](http://rpg.stackexchange.com)
- Puzzles, try [puzzling.stackexchange.com](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/)
- Game Recommendation/Shopping questions, this includes all questions that could be phrased like:

  - Best game for ... ?
  - Which game is like ... ?

Please [look around](/search) to see if your question has been asked before. It’s also OK to [ask and answer your own question](/helpcenter/self-answer).

If no site currently exists that will accept your question, you may [commit to](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) or [propose](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site) a new site at [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), the place where new Stack Exchange communities are democratically created.

---

## Meta canonical

---

Comment: I suggest reducing the long bulleted list of 7 categories and 16 examples to just a handful of comma separated examples (for example, "Magic: the Gathering, Checkers, Warhammer 40k, etc."). It would almost cut the length of the post in half. Does anyone else agree?

Comment: Yeah, something like that sounds good. We can turn it into a sentence instead of bullets no matter what, and we can either give a handful of example games, or categories, i.e. "Traditional board/card games, "German" games, collectible card games, miniature wargames, ..." We can always shift the full list into the meta canonical.

Comment: I thought about that, and I think it's a good idea, but I couldn't wrap my head around how you go about asking a canonical "What are some examples of games that are on topic here?" without it coming off as a shopping list question and getting closed.

Comment: @Rainbolt The meta canonical here would presumably be "what is the scope of this site?" not "what are some example games?" and part of the idea is to make this editing easy by not having to actually delete anything; we can just point to that from the help for extra details. But if really all there is to discuss is "what categories of games are on topic?" and we write a canonical answer including some examples, then that is perfectly fine. We are not going to pretend that anything in that vein *on meta* is a shopping/recommendation question.